# jQuery: selecting text without tag and wrapping it with one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a code you see below:

```
<div class="categories-list">
Description One
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>CATEGORY1</span>
        <span>CATEGORY2</span>
        <span>CATEGORY3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to select the text "Description one" which has no tag around it and wrap it with the tag (specifically h2) using jQuery, so the final code would look like:

```
<div class="categories-list">
<h2>Description One</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>CATEGORY1</span>
        <span>CATEGORY2</span>
        <span>CATEGORY3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I know that I can use wrap() function to get the second thing done. The selecting part is the one I've got the problem with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) can't do the job until you walk over the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the element:

```
$(".categories-list").contents().first().wrap("<h2 />");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MDhvY/

Comment: The magic here is contents http://api.jquery.com/contents/ which gets all of the child nodes (including text nodes (like you're interested in) and comments (!!).

Comment: genious! and that if there would be few texts with no tag spread around the document and I want to select all of them individually?

Comment: @zorza That might need more code that includes walking over these elements.

Comment: Thank you. This made my day. I almost gave up and made a search and replace function. There are so many so questions and answers that tell you this is not possible...